# Parse json coordinates with javasctipt

Tags: javascript, json

I need to find a closest coordonate and to put in arangement the cities which is closest.
In console log i need to have such of this: 8 city, 63.50590523722971;  5 city, 76.32168761236873
I think the coordonates is ok but how i can attach city attribute "city" to result[i] and fetch with it.

```
var locationcity = [
  {"city":"1 City","value":"61,90"},
  {"city":"2 City","value":"34,97"},
  {"city":"3 City","value":"21,63"},
  {"city":"4 City","value":"19,84"},
  {"city":"5 City","value":"0,81"},
  {"city":"6 City","value":"6,76"},
  {"city":"7 City","value":"43,64"},
  {"city":"8 City","value":"18,64"},
  {"city":"9 City","value":"10,61"},
]

function findClosest(locationcity){
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i < locationcity.length; i++){
        for(var j = 1; j < locationcity.length-1 ; j++){
            var x, y , r1 , r2;
            var id = locationcity[i].id;
            var coordinate_x = locationcity[i].value.split(",");
            var coordinate_y = locationcity[j].value.split(",");
            x = coordinate_x[0] - coordinate_y[0];
            y = coordinate_x[1] - coordinate_y[1];
            r1 = Math.pow(x, 2);
            r2 = Math.pow(y, 2);
            result[i] = Math.sqrt(r1 + r2);
        }
    }
   var closest = result.sort();
   $(closest).each(function(){
     var _this = $(this);
     console.log(_this);
   });
}
findClosest(locationcity);
```

Thanks

Comment: *Stack Overflow is not a place for people to finish your code for you.* What you're asking is very unclear. Edit your question to clarify where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The sort function can take an optional function as an argument:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

So instead of just storing the distance, store the city like this:

```
result[i] = {'distance': Math.sqrt(r1 + r2), 'city': locationcity[i].city };
```

And then when you sort you provide a sort function:

```
var closest = result.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a['distance'] - b['distance'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand if you wanted to display city to city distances and sort them, but this is what i would do, quickly, probably needs refactoring ;)

```
function findClosest(locationcity) {

var res = new Array();
for(var i=0; i < locationcity.length; i++) {

        var j = i + 1; // This is important to avoid duplications : ex.: 1 to 2 and 2 to 1
        while(j < locationcity.length ) {

            var x, y , r1 , r2;
            var cityA = locationcity[i].city;
            var cityB = locationcity[j].city;
            var coordinate_x = locationcity[i].value.split(",");
            var coordinate_y = locationcity[j].value.split(",");
            x = coordinate_x[0] - coordinate_y[0];
            y = coordinate_x[1] - coordinate_y[1];
            r1 = Math.pow(x, 2);
            r2 = Math.pow(y, 2);

            var distance_title  = cityA + " to " + cityB;
            var distance_value   = Math.sqrt(r1 + r2);

            res.push({
              "name" : distance_title,
              "dist" : distance_value
            });
            j++;
          }
     }

     var closest = res.sort(function (a, b) {
         return a['dist'] - b['dist'];
     });

     for(var key in closest) {
        console.log(closest[key]);
     }
}

findClosest(locationcity);
```

But once again, this is for sorting cities by distances between them !
Hope it will be usefull to you :)

Best regards.